# SharePoint 2016 ADFS Saml authentication and incoming email issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, adfs, incoming-email

We have a SharePoint Server 2016 farm and configured AD FS authentication via SAML. Email address is used as a user identifier.

When we enable incoming email on a document library. Depending on the value of the "Email Security Policy" option, here what happens :
[image]

1) , if we choose 'Accept email messages from any sender', we do receive email attachments on the document library

2) If we choose 'Accept email messaged based on document library permissions', attachment are no more received by the document library.

Now, here what I found in the ULS logs :

> No match in user info list. Input : toto.tata@domain.com

And the same user on the user info list has the following entry :

> Account :    i:05.t|trustedIdentityProvider|toto.tata@domain.com

In this context, how to tell SharePoint that toto.tata@domain.com is the same user as i:05.t|trustedIdentityProvider|toto.tata@domain.com ?

[Update 1] @Trevor : Here are the synced attributes

[image]

Comment: What attributes are you sync'ing to the UIL?

Comment: Hi @TrevorSeward, I've updated the description with the synced attributes.